# Fragment: RelativeLayout Visibility not changeable in OnCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

(Im using Kotlin)
So here is my OnCreateView in the Fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bots, container, false)

        BotDiv2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        startUp()
        return view
    }
```

and here is the xml of the relativelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/BotDiv2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="33.3"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/BotBtn1"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/uselessLevel1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/BotBtn1"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/BotBtn1"
                    android:text="Level:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/BotWorth1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/BotBtn1"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="$500"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/levelBot1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/BotBtn1"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/BotBtn1"
                    android:text="1" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

In want to use it in another Function, but this:

```
BotDiv2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

causes NPEs I also tried to use findViewById, but that causes an NPE as well (or not affecting, cuz of Kotlin's "?").

Comment: cause your id is `android:id="@+id/BotDiv1"` not `BotDiv2`

Comment: You need to intitialize BitDiv2 using findViewById(), BotDiv2 doesn't get magically initialized, like in wpf.

Comment: @Peter Bruins using `kotlin-android-extensions` no need to `findViewById`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the ID seemingly not being right, as mentioned in a comment above...

Since at this stage your `View` is not set for your `Fragment` yet (you haven't returned it to the framework), you can't call `findViewById` on the `Fragment` itself, but you can make a `findViewById` call on the newly inflated `View` instead:

```
val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bots, container, false)
val bd2 = view.findViewById(R.id.BotDiv2)
bd2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

If you're using Kotlin Android Extensions, you can do the same with this syntax:

```
val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bots, container, false)
view.BotDiv2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```