# Fragment: Change Visibility in function

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to use 
[this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060675/fragment-relativelayout-visibility-not-changeable-in-oncreateview)
to change the visibility of a RelativeLayout. That worked fine in the `OnCreateView` function, but i tried to add it into another function:

```
fun anzeigen(wert: Int){
        val inflater = dumpster.infl
        val container = dumpster.cont
        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bots, container, false)
        if (wert == 1){
            view.BotDiv1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```

To grab the inflater and the container I created this object to store them "globaly":

```
object dumpster {
    var infl: LayoutInflater? = null
    var cont: ViewGroup? = null
}
```

And here the OncreateView:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bots, container, false)
        dumpster.infl = inflater
        dumpster.cont = container

        //Test, workes fine view.BotDiv1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        return view
    }
```

Now it doesn't work. I Logged everything and the code executes, but the RelativeLayout just stayed invisible. (The function is obviously called from outside.)
No Crashes or anything

Comment: From what I understand your `view` (the one in `anzeigen` function) is visible. But did you check if `dumpster.cont` is visible?

Comment: cont (container) is needed for the View to inflate

Comment: Yea I get that but did you check if it's visible? Check `dumpster.cont!!.visibility == Visibility.VISIBLE`

Comment: i cant see invocation of `anzeigen() ` method.

Comment: @Mibac tried it, doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `anzeigen` you are inflating a view, but this view is not attached as a child to your `container`. To attach the new view to your container, you either have to call `container.addChild(view)` or inflate the view with `inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bots, container, **true**)`